# Adding whitespace to iText PDF Chunk

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to replace a word by inserting a Chunk on top of it.
The problem is that I'm trying to add space after text and it gets removed.

```
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(1);
cb.saveState();
Font fontbold = FontFactory.getFont("HELVETICA", 8, Font.BOLD);
Chunk textAsChunk = new Chunk("Text:", fontbold);
textAsChunk.setBackground(new BaseColor(255,255,255));
ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(textAsChunk), 32, 711, 0);
cb.stroke();
cb.restoreState();
```

I've also tried inserting `\t` but that didn't seem to work either. Any suggestions how to add spaces to the end of the string?

Comment: Please show enough code to allow reproducing the issue. In particular, how do you use the chunk? And a word of what do you want to replace.

Comment: @mkl The problem is the pdf is copy protected so I couldn't read the text with iText. I ended up making a white rectangle after the the chunk. Edited code

Comment: *The problem is the pdf is copy protected* - which pdf? Your question does not seem to start from an existing pdf. You probably should describe your use case better...

Comment: Ah, admittedly there is one hint that you change an existing pdf, your using a `stamper`. Ok. Have you tried `\u00a0` characters (commonly used as non-breaking spaces)? Other than that I'd propose to first draw a white rectangle as big as the original content you want to "replace" and then print text there without having to wonder whether it is long enough.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick thanks :) If you but it on as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While other trailing white space characters seem to be ignored here, a non-breaking space `\u00a0` can be used in this context to extend the area which is painted using the chunk background color.

Alternatively one can first draw a white rectangle as big as the original content one wants to "replace" and then print text there without having to wonder whether it is long enough.